# Android add buttons on image programmatically

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I have an image inside of a Constraint layout, I want to programmatically add buttons to it, so it makes sense with the image. Imagine an image of multiple squares where each square should correspond with a button.

I let it scale the image so it takes up the entire width of the screen.

I know the pixel coordinates of where the button should be located but I'm having trouble placing them correctly on the screen.

I tried converting the pixel location to the location on the screen by getting the width of the screen to calculate the multiplier which should be the same horizontally and vertically as it keeps the aspect ratio. But it's off by quite a bit.

```java
float mult = ((float) x) / ((float) SIZE_IMG.x); # x is the width of the screen
ConstraintLayout viewById = context.findViewById(R.id.constraintLayout);
ConstraintSet constraintSet = new ConstraintSet();

Button button = new Button(context);
button.setId(View.generateViewId());

viewById.addView(button);

constraintSet.clone(viewById);
constraintSet.connect(button.getId(), ConstraintSet.START, R.id.constraintLayout, ConstraintSet.START, (int) (mult * START.x));
constraintSet.connect(button.getId(), ConstraintSet.TOP, R.id.constraintLayout, ConstraintSet.TOP, (int) (mult * START.y));
constraintSet.applyTo(viewById);
```

X is found by

```java
ViewTreeObserver vto = viewById.getViewTreeObserver();
vto.addOnPreDrawListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener() {
    public boolean onPreDraw() {
        viewById.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnPreDrawListener(this);
        int finalHeight, finalWidth;
        finalHeight = viewById.getHeight();
        finalWidth = viewById.getWidth();
        yellowScoreBoard.initBoardOn(finalWidth, finalHeight, mainActivity);
        return true;
    }
});
```

Comment: The relations between Image pixels and there positions depends on how the image is displayed. If you are using an ImageView is dependent scaleType.
Simple multiply by a "mult" almost never correct.
It is always a linear screenx =  pixelsx * M + C. But the math for M and C can be complex depending on how the image gets there.

Provide more details or example code maybe some one can help you.

Comment: @hoford It is an ImageView inside of a ConstraintLayout, scaleType is set to `fitStart` so it will fill out the entire width of the screen. Those are the only elements present before adding the buttons. The image itself is just a .png in the drawable folder. Is that all the info needed or what more do you need to know? Your M would be my mult I think and C is an offset, but since it is the entire width of the screen there should be no offset?

Comment: FitStart is defined as : 
Compute a scale that will maintain the original src aspect ratio, but will also ensure that src fits entirely inside dst. At least one axis (X or Y) will fit exactly. START aligns the result to the left and top edges of dst.
So there will be blank space. Dependent on the relative aspect ratios.
(So typically one of the two constraints will be wrong.)
print all the values you set. Then in a postDelay get the positions of everything involved.  See if it makes sense to you.  
Alternatively build a simple demo of the of use case.

Comment: As the aspect ratio stays the same the multiplier should be the same for both the x and y axis which means I should be able to set everything relative to the top left corner. I'll try and simplify some things and will try to make a demo. Alternatively is there a way I can get the actual size of the image after it is auto scaled?

Comment: Good easy question imageView. getImageMatrix()
Search around for examples as to how to use it.

Comment: After playing around for a bit I noticed that when I place a button at 0,0 it's not in the corner, seems te be some kind of padding. When I remove the image view, the button is in the corner. I don't understand how the imageview can effect other views, as they only have constraints to the ConstraintLayout

Comment: I would have to see some XML to explain it.
It should be easy enough to generate a ConstraintLayout containing a button and ImageView in XML to demo the effect you are referring  to.